# How do I get Quinapalus to give me words that are 'anagram of word_a' in 'word_b'?

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, crosswords, quinapalus

I would like to use the [Quinapalus Matcher](https://www.quinapalus.com/matcher.html) to look for words that are made (with some prior jiggerypokery) from two letter sets, let's call them $word_a$ and $word_b$.

The letters in $word_a$ can be in any order (i.e. anagramed), and between $1$ and $n-1$ from $word_b$ in front and enter remaining $n-1$ to $1$ words behind.

E.g. if $word_a$ was *set* and $word_b$ was *stamen*, then *statesmen* would match, as it is **sta**(*set*)***men**, where the anagramed/scrambled *set* is used as *tes* in the middle.

I've had a look at both the *Compound patterns* and *wildcards*, but I can't figure out how to search for my use case, if it is possible at all.

Comment: Deleted my answer - I was wrong! I misunderstood your problem, thinking that you were looking for the two letter sets to themselves be variables -- if the sets are fixed, then athin and msh have perfectly workable answers.

Comment: @deusovi, that would be cool, but a step beyond what I need right now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm no expert in Qat but, is this the answer you're looking for?

> [ABC; AC=stamen; B=(/set)](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=ABC%3BAC%3Dstamen%3BB%3D(%2Fset)&ent=Search&dict=0)

Comment: To be fair, if both words are variables (as Deusovi said), I don't think there will be a workaround for it. The "stamen" part can be anything (e.g. it can be "......" for any 6-letters word), but the "set" part might be put in manually as the anagram in Qat cannot handle a variable.

Comment: [re your comment](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=ABC%3BAC%3Dstamen%3BB%3D%28%2Fs.t%29&ent=Search&dict=0)

Answer (score 8):

You can write an "… or … or …" list to get what you want. In your example:

> [s(/set)tamen|st(/set)amen|sta(/set)men|stam(/set)en|stame(/set)n](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=s%28%2Fset%29tamen%7Cst%28%2Fset%29amen%7Csta%28%2Fset%29men%7Cstam%28%2Fset%29en%7Cstame%28%2Fset%29n&ent=Search&dict=0)

Comment: Go upvote [athin's answer](/a/112302): it's more useful than this one. I'll leave this in place, though, since my solution works also.