# Can quinapalus anagram a subword it finds?

Tags: quinapalus

I'm trying to get quinapalus to [find subwords of a fixed length](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=ABC%3Dcosmopolitan%3BB%3D%28%2F.....%29&ent=Search&dict=0) and their anagrams.

This is my current search pattern:

```
ABC=cosmopolitan;B=(/.....)
```

Here is the current output, the subword and potential anagrams (manually found):

| current output | subword | manually found anagram |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c·osmop·olitan | osmop |  |
| co·smopo·litan | smopo |  |
| cos·mopol·itan | mopol |  |
| cosm·opoli·tan | opoli | polio |
| cosmo·polit·an | polit | pilot |
| cosmop·olita·n | olita |  |

Is there a way to get quinapalus to find these anagrams for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my earlier comment into a slightly longer answer, with inputs from PuzzleFerret & bobble :

I have good news & bad news.

### The good news

There may be a **Possible Potential Solution**:

The "Instruction" or "Pattern" should be `D=/B;B=(.....);ABC=cosmopolitan` which conveys the Idea that:

- ABC is the full-word (cosmopolitan),
- A is the Initial-Part (eg, c or co or cos, etc),
- B is the Sub-Part with 5 letters (eg osmop, smopo, mopol, etc),
- C is the Terminal-Part (eg olitan, litan, itan, etc) &
- D is an anagram of B.

**Now this should generate all anagrams D of all 5-letter Sub-Parts B.**

### The bad news

Qat has some incomplete functionality or unfinished areas and throws errors.

In the Documentation at https://www.quinapalus.com/qat.html , variables are listed on the LHS only; there seems to be no way to include variables on the RHS ; Attempting that gives errors.
Eg "ABC=rotator;B=.." works & "ABC=rotator;D" also works, but "ABC=rotator;D=A" throws error over variable on RHS

Most Importantly, D=/B is not working because currently variables cannot be anagrammed (thanks to bobble for clarifying this)

**Conclusion: Currently there is no way to put the Possible Potential Solution through Qat to generate the list.**

We could try contacting the tool owner via https://www.quinapalus.com/ or "mail at quinapalus dot com" and get more thoughts on the matter.

Comment: It's not necessary to put a variable on the RHS - a non-equation `<things>;/B;<more things>` would add the constraint "/B must be a word" (non-equation things are just required to be words). The fundamental problem is that [**variables cannot be anagrammed**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112295/how-do-i-get-quinapalus-to-give-me-words-that-are-anagram-of-word-a-in-word-b#comment316873_112302)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting input , @bobble ! That could be yet another issue to add to the list of incomplete functionality. (A) The Point about variables on the RHS is also valid : Check "D=b;B=(.....);ABC=cosmopolitan" which gives some output & "D=B;B=(.....);ABC=cosmopolitan" which gives errors, because of the variable on the RHS. (B) Trying anagrams with variables, I encountered more strange things; Check "/i;B=(...);ABC=cosmopolitan" which gives a short correct output & "/I;B=(...);ABC=cosmopolitan", which uses undefined variable CAPITAL I with anagram, but generates huge wrong output.

Comment: A little more testing seems to suggest that it is incorrect or at least inaccurate to say that "variables cannot be anagrammed" ; @bobble , **I was able to make variables be anagrammed** .... Check "ABC;AC=stamen;B=(/s.t);/A" which tries to anagram "sta" through /A and correctly shows "0 Solutions" while "ABC;AC=stamen;B=(/s.t);/C" tries to anagram "men" through /C and correctly shows "1 Solution" .... Even "ABC;AC=stamen;B=(/s.t);/B" tries to anagram "tes" through /B and correctly shows "1 Solution" .... Hence variables can be anagrammed !! Overall, variables on the RHS is the Core Problem

Comment: the variables at the end of those expressions aren't being anagrammed: if I [remove the `/`](ABC;AC=stamen;B=(/s.t);B) from that last one I get the same result. A variable can *be an anagram* (i.e. you can store an anagram in a variable) but cannot *be anagrammed* by the program

Comment: I agree with what you say , @bobble , that Qat is not anagramming B with /B .... But either /B is supposed to mean anagramming or /B should be invalid syntax .... Qat throws errors in other areas but not here .... Qat seems to be trying to execute something when a variable is given in anagram, but that is not succeeding .... Maybe it ignores the / in such cases .... Ok the Current Summary is : Qat Documentation is incomplete, Qat has incomplete functionality & Variable Anagramming is not working ....

Comment: One last comment, which I think explains things , @bobble , and makes sense atleast to me. When we use B or /B , we are telling Qat that B or /B should be a word; When B has already been assigned a value [ eg by ABC=cosmopolitan or B=(/s.t) ] then /B will not generate more values for B; When we use D=/B, only then we will generate anagrams of the letters of B and assign word values to D; While /B is valid syntax, it will only check that the value is a valid word but will not generate output of Possible values; D=/B will mean that D is anagram of B, but variables are not allowed on the RHS.

Comment: it doesn't throw errors because it *is* a valid expression, it's just not the expected one. `/` only acts on **elements**, and variables are not elements. So the `/` acts on all elements after it - which is none, so it ends up being a wash - and then `B` as lonely variable kicks in

Comment: Oh , now it is totally clear ; thanks @bobble for clarifying ; I have updated the answer with this Important Point